# Data in App component in beforeMount is not available

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am building Vue app. I have main App, where I am loading components

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="__layout" v-if="!$route.meta.plainLayout">
            <app-navbar></app-navbar>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <app-menu :current="current"></app-menu>
                    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
                        <app-alerts></app-alerts>
                        <router-view />
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="__layout" v-if="$route.meta.plainLayout">
            <router-view />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am loading user with permissions here

```
    [...]
    created: function() {
        this.$http.get('/api/users/me')
            .then(response => {
                this.$store.commit('loadCurrent', response.data.data);
            })
    }
    [...]
```

It works good. For checking permissions I use simple mixin

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    can: function (permission) {
      return this.$store.state.permissions.map(p => p.name).indexOf(permission) !== -1;
    }  
  }
});
```

Now, I want to check permissions in component (which is injected it router-view).

```
[..]
beforeMount: function() {
        if (!this.can('view-clients')) {
            this.$router.push({ 'name': 'dashboard' }, () => {
                this.$toasted.show('You do not have permissions!');
            });
        };
[..]
}
```

However, the store is empty, the user isn't loaded!

Strangely seems like main App created didn't completed before loaded component's beforeMount.

How can I check permissions in component which is loaded into router-view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard.
[Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

> called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.

```
import store from "./store";

export default {
  ...
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from ,next) {
    if (store.state.permissions.map(p => p.name).indexOf("view-clients") === -1) {
       next({ "name": "dashboard" });
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

> The `beforeRouteEnter` guard does **NOT** have access to `this`, because the
>   guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new
>   entering component has not even been created yet.

So to access `store` you have to import it manually.